# Creating dynamic layout using button

Tags: android, textview, android-relativelayout, onclicklistener

I want to create dynamically relative layout after pushing the button.
I wrote such examplary class with constructor which creates TextView:

```
public static class CreateTextView {
    public static TextView textView;
    public Context context;
    public CharSequence text;
    public int textSize;
    public int textViewWidth;
    public int textViewHeight;
    public int layoutRule;

    public CreateTextView(Context context, CharSequence text, int textSize, int textViewWidth, int textViewHeight, int layoutRule) {
        textView = new TextView(context);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                textViewWidth, textViewHeight
        );
        textViewParams.addRule(layoutRule);

        textView.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
        textView.setText(text);
        textView.setTextSize(textSize);
    }

    public View getView() {
        return textView;
    }
}
```

And then in onClickListener I execute it like this:

```
connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            createTextView = new CreateTextView(getApplicationContext(), charSequence, 30, -2, -2, 14);
            relativeLayout.addView(CreateTextView.textView);
        }
    });
```

My first problem is that I have to make textView static field because "non-static field cannot be referenced from static context". But for now I can live with that although if you have another idea for that I would be grateful ;)

The main problem is that I want to change the content of textView objects (created like above) dynamically. I have another thread which provides data and I want to have this data displayed on-line in those text views. Button will be deleted after being pushed so option of refreshing text views by pushing button again is unacceptable.

Is it even possible?

Answer (score 0):

Adam, your code looks bad, but let start with things, that you can do/improve:
1. If you want to create static method for creating TextView - ok, do this in not static class, but in normal public class, with static method createTextView, that is returning TextView. I believe, that it should look like this (I was not compiling it, so possibly you will have to make there small changes to make it compilable):

```
public class CreateTextView {
    public static TextView createTextView(Context context, CharSequence text, int textSize, int textViewWidth, int textViewHeight, int layoutRule) {
        TextView textView = new TextView(context);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                textViewWidth, textViewHeight
        );
        textViewParams.addRule(layoutRule);

        textView.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
        textView.setText(text);
        textView.setTextSize(textSize);

        return textView;
    }
}
```

2. In your activity/fragment class, where you have connectButton.setOnClickListener, you are adding TextView member of class, for example:

   private TextView mMyTextView;
3. Then onClickListner should look like:

   ```
   connectButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
       @Override
       public void onClick(View v) {
           myTextView = CreateTextView.createTextView(getApplicationContext(), charSequence, 30, -2, -2, 14);
           relativeLayout.addView(myTextView);
       }});
   ```
4. Then changing your newly created TextView by data from other thread, can be done in many ways, depending on architecture, your preferences... (by contentResolver, LocalBroadcastManager,....). And this you are doing by working with myTextView

Answer (score 0):

Before you answered, I did it like this:

```
public class CreateTextView {
    public TextView textView;
    public Context context;
    public CharSequence text;
    public int textSize;
    public int textViewWidth;
    public int textViewHeight;
    public int layoutRule;

    public CreateTextView(RelativeLayout relativeLayout, Context context, CharSequence text, int textSize, int textViewWidth, int textViewHeight, int layoutRule) {
        textView = new TextView(context);

        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams textViewParams = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
                textViewWidth, textViewHeight
        );
        textViewParams.addRule(layoutRule);

        textView.setLayoutParams(textViewParams);
        textView.setText(text);
        textView.setTextSize(textSize);
        relativeLayout.addView(textView);
    }

    public void setContent(CharSequence charSequence) {
        textView.setText(charSequence);
    }
}
```

As you can see I added RelativeLayout object to constructor arguments and get rid of all static types. It works fine and now I can change the text using setContent() method. But now I have next question: Is there any option to change TextView content without using setText() method?